# why the array (collCells) is showing empty while passing the array elements from different ViewController in swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I want to pass the elements from array (items2) to an array (collCells) which is in different viewcontroller but collCells is showing an empty square brackets

VC 1 (stctView) :-

```
var items = [Item]()
var items2 = [Item]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if items[indexPath.row].checked == false{

        items[indexPath.row].checked = true
        items2.append(items[indexPath.row])
        saveData()
        saveData2()
        print(items2)

    }else {
        let remItem = items[indexPath.row]
        if let index:Int = self.items2.index(where: {$0.name == remItem.name && $0.checked == remItem.checked && $0.buyPrice == remItem.buyPrice && $0.rank == remItem.rank && $0.symbol == remItem.symbol}) {
            self.items2.remove(at: index)
        }
        saveData()
        saveData2()
        print(items2)
        items[indexPath.row].checked = false

    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Collection" {
        let DVC = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController
        DVC.collCells = items2
    }
}
```

vc 2 (CollectionViewController):-

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var collCells = [Item]()

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,     cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

collCells = stctView.items2  

// Configure the cell
cell.coinName.text = collCells[indexPath.row].name
cell.buyPrice.text = "\(String(describing: collCells[indexPath.row].buyPrice))"
cell.rank.text = "\(String(describing: collCells[indexPath.row].rank))"

return cell
   }

}
```

Comment: Do you find values in prepare for segue method, when checked with break point?, use a break point to see values for item2

Comment: just tried that but the program keeps running even after setting up a break point

Comment: try to clean the xcode, or restart it, it should stop at the debugger

Comment: on other functions the break point is working, but on this one it is not even after restarting xcode completely

Comment: looks like your prepareForSegue is not being called, delete this function and add it again:

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prepare for segue function looks old, please use it as following:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

}
```

Comment: it worked thanks! but in the vc 2  it gives me this error 'Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x107df8a18) to 'Ticky.CollectionViewCell' (0x104c63ae0)' in front of this line 'let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell'